# How to modify Matomo/Piwik database connections dynamically?

Tags: php, database-connection, matomo

I run Piwik on a VPS to record usage statistics of a web app I run. I have currently got it deployed as a manual install, and have recently set about the task of Dockerising it. In line with twelve factor app principles, I would like to set it up to read database credentials dynamically, probably from environment variables in the container; this will allow me to use the same image regardless of environment too.

However, I am struggling to work out how to do this. As I see it there are four approaches:

1. Put `<?php echo getenv('PIWIK_DATABASE_USER') ?>` statements into the `config.ini.php` config file. However, this results in an error, and I wonder whether this is in fact just an INI file and not a PHP file at all. It seems that [other folks](https://forum.piwik.org/t/how-to-configure-the-database-variables-via-env-vars/21023) have [struggled with this too](https://forum.piwik.org/t/database-config-from-environment-variable-mysql-url/12769).
2. Reset the global const `PIWIK_USER_PATH` to point to a different configuration/temp base folder using the bootstrap script. I am fairly sure this would work, but is my least favoured solution, since if I want to create a new environment or change an existing one, I have to rebuild the container image.
3. Use a plugin or the bootstrap system to capture the [database credentials event](https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/events#dbgetdatabaseconfig) and change them before they are used
4. Use a plugin or the bootstrap system to overwrite the config using `Config::getInstance()->__set()`.

So, it seems that either the bootstrap device or a plugin is a good approach. I can get a `bootstrap.php` to be read, but it looks like it is called quite early on in the bootstrap process, and the `Config` singleton is not populated at that point. For example if I try to use (4) here, I just get an error. I am using this demo code:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Piwik\Config::getInstance()->database['host'] ='localhost';
```

And here is the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Piwik\Container\ContainerDoesNotExistException: The root container has not been created yet. in /var/www/html/core/Container/StaticContainer.php:40\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/core/Container/StaticContainer.php(80): Piwik\Container\StaticContainer::getContainer()\n#1 /var/www/html/core/Config.php(64): Piwik\Container\StaticContainer::get('Piwik\\Config')\n#2 /var/www/html/bootstrap.php(4): Piwik\Config::getInstance()\n#3 /var/www/html/index.php(15): require_once('/var/www/html/b...')\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/core/Container/StaticContainer.php on line 40

I have tried a demo plugin as well, and I have enabled it in the `config.ini.php`, but it does not appear to be included or instantiated, and so its `init()` method is not in a position to change anything. Here is the plugin code:

```
<?php
// plugins/DatabaseConfiguration/DatabaseConfiguration.php             

namespace Piwik\Plugins\DatabaseConfiguration;

echo "Hello";

class DatabaseConfiguration extends \Piwik\Plugin
{
    protected function init()
    {
    }
}
```

(Note the temporary `echo` to output something random in the web app when the class is included by Piwik).

Here is my turning it on in config:

```
PluginsInstalled[] = "DatabaseConfiguration"
```

[One logged issue](https://forum.piwik.org/t/installing-piwik-in-paas-uhurucloud-com-connection-parameters-in-environment-variables/8155) about this includes an offer from a contributor to undertake the necessary work via private consultancy. However, I am hoping to do the necessary hacking myself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question turns out to be a good rubber duck! Here is my solution. I used the plugin approach, it just needed a bit of extra configuration.

In particular I was missing these lines in `global.ini.php`:

```
; The below is appended to the global.ini.php config file

[Plugins]
Plugins[] = DatabaseConfiguration
```

Even though there is another `[Plugins]` section this seems to work fine, so I have done an append in the `Dockerfile` thus:

```
# Inject settings file here
COPY config/config.ini.php /var/www/html/config/config.ini.php
COPY config/global.ini.php.append /tmp/global.ini.php.append

# Append the global config to the existing file (this did not seem to be settable
# in the standard config file)
RUN cat /tmp/global.ini.php.append >> /var/www/html/config/global.ini.php
```

It would have been nice to add this to the `config.inc.php` but it did not seem to work for me.

Finally the following code is installed in `plugins/DatabaseConfiguration/DatabaseConfiguration.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * A Piwik plugin to set database credentials based on environment variables
 */

namespace Piwik\Plugins\DatabaseConfiguration;

class DatabaseConfiguration extends \Piwik\Plugin
{
    public function registerEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Db.getDatabaseConfig' => 'getDatabaseConfig'
        ];
    }

    public function getDatabaseConfig(&$dbConfig)
    {
        $dbConfig['host'] = getenv('PIWIK_DATABASE_HOST');
        $dbConfig['dbname'] = getenv('PIWIK_DATABASE_NAME');
        $dbConfig['username'] = getenv('PIWIK_DATABASE_USER');
        $dbConfig['password'] = getenv('PIWIK_DATABASE_PASSWORD');
    }
}
```

For Git users, this plugin is [available here](https://github.com/halfer/piwik-database-configuration).

When I get a moment I will see if the Piwik devs will let me add this feature to their plugins list.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful!

To activate the plugin in the latest version of Piwik (i.e. Matomo 3.5) you can do this: 

`./console plugin:activate DatabaseConfiguration`

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful to get this working in Matomo 3.6. I also had to listen on the Event Tracker.getDatabaseConfig because apparently the piwik.php tracker uses a different API to initialize the DB connection. Also, start the plugin development with `./console generate:plugin --name="PlatformDatabaseConfiguration"` just adding the class will complain about it not being compatible with this version.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up @Berdir - I haven't upgraded yet!